# syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) in laravel when try to run like localhost/project_name/public

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

> syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING)

in laravel when try to run like `localhost/project_name/public`

And same project running throught php artisan serve cmd . So I was not able to understand why this is happening .

[image: Click Here to see the actual error]

Comment: Can you post code where error has occurred?

Comment: What happened in /storage/framework/views/c3777xxxx.php line 19. Open it and show it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Actually I am creating website and I have done with it now. Till now I run project through artisan command but  now i want to run project after hitting localhost/project_name and it should be run . Website is static

Comment: It is minor syntax error in php. You should check code on the line which causing issue or post that line here.

Comment: In 95 pct of cases semicolon has been forgotten in line before.

Comment: Thanks Guys for helping me....working fine now , problem comes when <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> this line is find in code . I don't know why it is happening , but other hand I problem is SALVED

Answer (score 0):

Set Php tag **short_open** 0 or Off either in php.ini or .htaccess

For .htaccess add the following line

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    php_value short_open_tag 0
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```